# Swiftで引数にクロージャを渡すときの書き方

Tags: swift, objective-c

Swiftにて、UITableViewの読み込みが完了したことを検知したいのですが、
http://qiita.com/corocorococoro/items/1c80681cd7e1fddc3ba3
を参考に、

```
extension UITableView {
　・・・
}
```

で書いてみようとしたのですが、上記参考URLの

```
- (void)reloadDataAndWait:(void(^)(void))waitBlock {
    [self reloadData];
    if (waitBlock) {
        waitBlock();
    }
}
```

をSwiftでどのように書いたらいいかわかりません。

Answer (score 1):

Swiftにそのまま移植すると下記になります。

```
extension UITableView {
    func reloadDataAndWait(waitBlock: (() -> ())?) {
        reloadData()
        if let waitBlock = waitBlock {
            waitBlock()
        }
    }
}
```

使い方は次のようになりますが、

```
tableView.reloadDataAndWait { 
    NSLog("numberofsection %d", self.tableView.numberOfSections)
}
```

リンク先のさらに先のStackOverflowの回答のコメントにもあるように、このコードは、

```
tableView.reloadData()
NSLog("numberofsection %d", self.tableView.numberOfSections)
```

と`reloadData()`の後に続けて処理を書いてるのと全く同じ意味です。
なのでわざわざこのようなメソッドを作る意味はありませんよ。

Comment: 仰る通り、このメソッドはうまく動かなかったので、reloadDataの後に
dispatch_asyncを使用することで、実現できました。
質問のタイトルとは離れてしまいましたが、ありがとうございました。